# using same bundle identifier in info.plist (Xcode) for different builds

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I followed instructions given at [this link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services) to create provisioning profile that has push notifications enabled. According to it I renamed bundle identifier in `info.plist` as **com.domain.pushApp** which worked fine for the first build (**app_1.0**). When I changed product name (**app_1.1**), I expected a different build, but new build overwrites old one. I tried changing version number from 1.0 to 2.0 with no luck. Can I have two builds with same bundle identifier?

I tried creating new provisioning profile with bundle identifier name **com.domain.*** but that doesn't not work for push notifications.

[image: xcode screen shot]

I must have missed something obvious but not able to find it. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to keep several builds of your app using the sample bundle ID, a simple solution is to archive each version that you want to keep.

you can then access them later in Organizer > Archives.

But there is no way to have two apps with the same bundle identifier on the phone. sorry. maybe you should try develop an in-house distribution app (an in-house AppStore) for a faster switch between the versions of your app.

Comment: thanks for the reply teriiehina, that gives a possible solution.  is there no way I can install multiple builds (with different product name) on devices?

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't understand the app were overriding on the phone. No there is no way to have two apps with the same bundle identifier on the phone. sorry. maybe you should try develop an in-house distribution app (an in-house AppStore) for a faster switch between the versions of your app.

Comment: you welcome. I updated my answer to have it complete in regard to your question.